How to change tf2's default storage time
I've learned that tf2 stores a time snapshot for every transform for up to 10 seconds by default from this link. My question is how can I change default storage time from 10 seconds to 5 seconds?

I did not test this, but based on a quick glance at the header files I assume the buffer size is controlled by the cache_time parameter of its constructor.

Yes, I think it worked. I changed the BUFFER_CORE_DEFAULT_CACHE_TIME variable in the buffer_core.h file which is in the /opt/ros/<ros_version>/include/tf2/tf2.

Ok, that will change the default, but you could also just add a custom value for cache_time to the constructor of your buffer instance. Anyway, glad it works!
